# How to use GetPropertyValueSafely from CommonLibrary.NET?

Tags: c#, dll, system.reflection

When using the [CommonLibrary.Net](http://commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/), how does one use the `GetPropertyValueSafely()` function correctly?

I want to do something like this:

```
public static string APP_TITLE = ComLib.ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValueSafely(Application.ProductName);
```

but I need to add a second parameter, and I don't understand enough yet to know what is asked for.  Here is the syntax usage from the documentation file:

```
public static Object GetPropertyValueSafely(
    Object obj,
    PropertyInfo propInfo
)
```

This are the parameter requirements:

> Parameters obj Type: System..::..Object Object whose property is to be retrieved.
>
> propInfo Type: System.Reflection..::..PropertyInfo Property name.

So what do I put for `object`?  I tried this, too:

```
public static string APP_TITLE;
ComLib.ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValueSafely(APP_TITLE, Application.ProductName);
```

but that's not the answer either.

I also tried this:

```
public static string APP_TITLE = ComLib.Reflection.ReflectionUtils.GetPropertyValue((object)APP_TITLE, Application.ProductName).ToString();
```

...which compiles, but it throws a runtime type error from the library.

Thanks for the help (I'm just starting to get this stuff into my head).

Comment: @Ramhound - Can you show me how it works?  I've spent over an hour trying to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static readonly string APP_TITLE = (string)ComLib.ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValueSafely(new object(), 
    ComLib.Reflection.ReflectionUtils.GetProperty(typeof(Application), "ProductName"));
```

**NB:** Technically, passing `new object()` to the `PropertyInfo`'s `GetValue` method should throw a `TargetException`. However, since this is a static property, it seems to work.

Comment: It gives this in the error listing: `Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' 
`

Comment: @BGM: In that case, since `Application.ProductName` is a static property, you should pass `null` as the first argument to the `GetPropertyValueSafely` method.

Comment: @BGM: Which would work if there wasn't a bug in the `GetPropertyValueSafely` method that prevents it from working with static properties.

Comment: It says, `cannot implicitly convert type object to string` where the "miscast" is in the first function call, so I added a `toString()` to the end, and then it crashes on runtime with 'System.TypeInitializationException'

Comment: Ah, the stacktrace says, "The type initializer cannot be null"

Comment: @BGM: The `GetPropertyValueSafely` method will throw an exception if you pass `null` as the first argument. Unfortunately, for static properties, there is no instance of the class to pass. Passing a dummy object seems to work.

Comment: This is it (it works well): `
  public static readonly string APP_TITLE = ComLib.ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValueSafely(typeof(string),
ComLib.Reflection.ReflectionUtils.GetProperty(typeof(Application), "ProductName")).ToString();`  Thank you for your help.